# Set the docroot for HTTPS access to subdomains/sub on Plesk

Tags: plesk, document-root

We have an odd situation with the docroot of our web-server administered in Plesk. In hosting settings a sub domain points to a path Document Root: `/subdomain/sub` the files however to not live there. They are taken from `/httpsdocs` with permanent SEO-Safe redirect from HTTP to HTTPS `on`.

Everything works so I'm reluctant to change anything but the annoying thing is that when clicking on `File Manager` in `Websites & Domains` it takes me to the wrong folder.

Btw. in the PHP Settings we see this:

```
{DOCROOT} for the document root directory of the website. The current value is /home/httpd/vhosts/customer/subdomains/sub. The HTTPS document root directory is /home/httpd/vhosts/customer/httpsdocs.
{WEBSPACEROOT} for the document root directory of the subscription's primary website.
{TMP} for the directory which stores temporary files.
```

In fact it would be great if the virtualhost would take the root from the `/subdomains/sub` instead of `httpsdocs`. Is this possible?